# How to put text at the center of LinearLayout horizontally?

Tags: android, xml

How to put text at the center of LinearLayout horizontally?
Do I have to use layout_margin?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" // this does not work
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this attribute to your linearlayout.

```
    <LinearLayout>
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    </LinearLayout>
```

or else change `TextView` like below :

```
<TextView  
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Hello"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
/>
```

Comment: I simplified my question too much.

Answer (score 1):

you have to use  `gravity` instead of `layout_gravity`

Comment: It does not work either. I will work if I change width to fill_parent. I cannot do that in my real project.

Comment: Then maybe you can try plaing with padding. Why can not you change it in "fill_parent" ?